# R Mutating character column under conditions of other character columns and a lookup character vector

Tags: r, dplyr, conditional-statements

In an R dataframe I want to mutate a character column under conditions of other character columns and a lookup character vector.

So for example:

```
Mydata %>%
mutate(CharColumn1 = case_when(
Charcolumn2 %in% Charvector & Charcolumn3 == "character1" ~ "character2",
Charcolumn2 %in% Charvector & Charcolumn3 == "character2" ~ "character1",
TRUE ~ Charcolumn3))
```

I used the example above, but didn't work. In fact it changed nothing at all. I also tried Ifelse, but that mutated the values into TRUE or FALSE instead of "character1" or "character2". Last but not least I tried to do it this way:

```
Mydata %>%
charcolumn1[charcolumn2 %in% charvector & charcolumn3 == "character1"] <- "character2" %>%
charcolumn1[charcolumn2 %in% charvector & charcolumn3 == "character2"] <- "character1"
```

But this method gives me an error: "target of assignment expands to non-language object"

Can somebody help me out here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example so we can run it on our own machines? It is quickest way to get an answer on here. Thanks :)

Comment: You need to assign the results of function calls. `NewData <- Mydata %>% mutate( ...`

Answer (score 1):

Your code works as-is if you wrap your conditional statements in `()`:

```
Mydata %>%
  mutate(
    CharColumn1 = case_when(
      (Charcolumn2 %in% Charvector) & (Charcolumn3 == "character1") ~ "character2",
      (Charcolumn2 %in% Charvector) & (Charcolumn3 == "character2") ~ "character1",
      TRUE ~ Charcolumn3))
```

Output:

```
   Charcolumn2 Charcolumn3 CharColumn1
1            d  character1  character1
2            e  character3  character3
3            d  character1  character1
4            a  character1  character2
5            a  character3  character3
6            c  character3  character3
7            b  character2  character1
8            c  character3  character3
9            b  character1  character2
10           a  character2  character1
```

Data:

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(40)
N <- 10
Charvector <- c("a", "b")
Mydata <- data.frame(Charcolumn2 = sample(letters[1:5], replace=TRUE, size=N), 
                     Charcolumn3 = sample(paste0("character",1:3), replace=TRUE, size=N),
                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks very much 42 and andrew_reece for helping me out! The combination of your answers solved my problem. First assigning the results and then wrapping the conditions in ().